# Nginx rules conversion

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rules, conf, conversion

I have these htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and I used an online converter and this is what it gave me, however, it doesn't work, so I'm not really sure what's wrong with it.

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" - what actually happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nginx you don't use `rewrite` for front controllers, instead use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files). Your configuration should look something like this:

```
server {
    ...
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~ (.+)/$ {
        return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
    }
}
```